# I want to put the TimerThread inside of Timer into a ThreadGroup

Tags: java

Without using any sort of any nasty reflection. Any quick/easy way to do it (w/o copying and pasting the Timer code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Timer`, try [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead. Combine a call to [`Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29) with a custom [`ThreadFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) that creates the thread with the group you want. Of course, there's much more flexibility available with executors and thread factories, but this most closely mimics the working of a timer (single thread per timer).

Comment: I figured this was the right way to go, but I'm always faced with resistance in the form of "if it ain't broke, don't fix it"

Answer (score 0):

If I were to attempt this, I would look at the source code for timerthread and see if it has a well known name, and then locate it via `Thread.enumerate`.

Also, why? I ask because I've never found threadgroups to be all that useful.

Comment: In Effective Java by Joshua Bloch, he recommends never using thread groups.

Comment: I'm a stickler for organization, this helps when I'm debugging, I want to be able to group them and not worry about them.

Answer (score 0):

a new Thread, if not given an explicit ThreadGroup, will first ask the SecurityManager for the target ThreadGroup, then fall back to the current Thread's ThreadGroup.  so, you can create the Timer from a Thread in the desired ThreadGroup, or temporarily install a SecurityManager with the desired ThreadGroup (note that this will have a global affect, so this is a little sketchier).

Comment: In the application in question, all the initialization (including Timers) are in the beginning. If I pass in a ThreadGroup to other threads, which ThreadGroup takes precendence? The SecurityManager's or the ThreadGroup passed in when constructing it?

Comment: like i said in my comment, the rules i mentioned are only if a Thread is not given an explicit ThreadGroup in its constructor.